# How do I store an instance of a class created by a constructor so variables within in can be called later?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, initialization

For Example: I have a deck of cards, with a constructor Card(char,int). I initialize 52 instances of card. Then using a method within Card, I call GetName() which should return a string of char + int; So if I initialize it as Card c1 = new Card(d,1); and call c1.GetName(); it should return c1. However, the program is choosing a different card and assigning all instances of cards that name.

```
The Code is rather long so I have it copied here: http://pastebin.com/7akeFgs0
```

I've looked into Garbage Collection and I'm not sure what to do if that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables Name, Flip, and SuitNumber should not be static. Otherwise, there's only one Name, Flip and SuitNumber for all your instances.

By the way, they should also start with a lowercase letter, but that's not related with the problem.

Comment: Jeez it was that easy. I was checking all the complicated solutions and didn't even bother to check that...

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor

```
public Card(int Suitnumber, int Number){
                 SuitNumber = Suitnumber;}
```

You don't use the 2nd parameter!

Answer (score 0):

In java `chars` are `int`s so `char + int = int`. What you likely want is `"" + char + int;` which returns a String.

Also, you're really overcomplicating the deck generation. I'd suggest something like this:

```
public class Card
{

    char suit;
    int value;

    public Card(char suit, int value)
    {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return "" + suit + value;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class Deck
{

    static final char[] suits = new char[] {
            'h', 'd', 'c', 's'
    };
    static final int[] values = new int[] {
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
    };

    List<Card> cards;

    public Deck()
    {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        for (char suit : suits)
        {
            for (int value : values)
            {
                cards.add(new Card(suit, value));
            }
        }
    }

    public void shuffle()
    {
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
    }
}
```

You could also look into using Java Enums for your suits. It would allow for easy comparison and giving each suit a human readable String.